# ‘Positive’ commutator argument to control norms of a distributions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, microlocal-analysis

I am currently reading some lecture notes about microlocal analysis and the author gives a simple example of the ‘positive’ commutator argument, that I do not really understand. Let me explain it.

Let $u \in \mathcal{D}’(\mathbb{R})$ : we want to estimate $\lvert u(1) \lvert^2$ in terms of $\lvert u(-1) \lvert^2$ and $D_xu := \frac{1}{i} \partial_x u$. Let $\chi = 1_{[-1,1]}$ be the characteristic function of the interval $[-1,1] $. We have

$$ -\lvert u(1) \lvert^2  + \lvert u(-1) \lvert^2  = \int i [D_x,\chi] u \cdot \bar{u} \, dx  = i^{-1} \left( \int D_x u \cdot \chi \bar{u} \, dx - \int \chi u \cdot \bar{D_x u} \, dx \right),$$
which is equal to $2 \, \mathrm{Im} \langle D_xu, \chi u \rangle$.
The the author says that if $D_x u = 0$, the first equality reveals that what really provides control of $\lvert u(1) \lvert^2$ is the fact that $\chi$ has negative derivative at 1. What does it mean ?

It seems to me the derivative of $\chi$ at 1 is $-\delta$, the Dirac mass at 1. But I do not understand how it is used in the first equality, and also how $D_x \chi$ really is (in the commutator $[D_x,\chi] $ ) in general and how to find the right hand side of the second equality.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Edit : and ‘positive’ means the ‘good’ sign (the one that allows us to control), which is the negative sign here..

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't read too much into this kind of informal comments. What is written there is simply the definition of $[D_x, \chi]$ and integration by parts. By definition,
$$
[D_x, \chi]u=D_x(\chi u)-\chi\, D_x u.$$
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty  [D_x, \chi]u\cdot\overline{u}\, dx &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty D_x(\chi u) \overline u\, dx - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \chi D_xu\cdot \overline u\, dx \\ 
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\chi u \cdot D_x\overline u\, dx - \int_{-\infty}^\infty D_x u \cdot \chi \overline u \, dx .
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

The rest does not make much sense to me, since $D_x u=0$ means that $u$ is the constant distribution.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes sure it is a bit strange.. apparently this example shows why the negative sign of the derivative is important in order to control (since he generalizes this example afterwards). However, how do you find the first equality ? Does it deal with that derivative of $\chi $ ?

Comment: That's just the definition of the commutator.